# How do I transfer files from Unix machine connected using Putty to windows PC through SCP command?

Tags: unix, scp

In my office I have only few machines installed with WinSCP to copy files between UNIX boxes and windows. 
My problem is how do I copy file using SCP command from UNIX machines connected via PUTTY.

I tried the below command :

```
scp final_result.log 6696xxx@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:C:/share
```

But I am unable to do it. I am getting the error as

```
ssh: connect to host 10.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

I got the server IP using ipconfig from windows. Is that the correct IP or should I have some other IP ?

Comment: 1) you don't have `sshd` server on windows, I believe. 2) SCP command doesn't work with windows-style paths starting with `C:/` since it conflicts with scp delimiter. Solution is to transfer files using WinSCP in opposite direction.

Comment: The problem is we dont have admin permissions to install. It takes time to raise tickets and get them done. Is there any other way apart from SCP

Comment: you can't achieve it only with putty executable. There is `PSCP` which should work similar way as `scp` on windows (not sure if needs to be installed, but I believe not): http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks. I will try on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Jakuje's answer I tried PSCP using Super Putty to upload and download files from UNIX box to my windows PC.

Super Putty has a built in option to integrate PSCP.exe into it by mentioning the path of PSCP. 
Used this [link](http://www.mcpressonline.com/networking/emulation/techtip-superputty-the-enhanced-putty-ssh-client-gui.html) to integrate.